# Move inline element within block element

Tags: html, css

I have a `<nav>` element. Inside that `<nav>` element I have links (as you do). I have some javascript that changes which link is the current page via its class attribute when it is clicked. I would like that link element to be promoted to the top of the nav bar when it has the current page class. For example:

```
<nav>
  <a>Link 1</a>
  <a class="currentpage">Link 2</a>
</nav>
```

To help conceptualize things, this nav is currently being displayed as a simple list of links rather than as a bar across the top of the page. I just want Link 2 to appear at the top of the list when its class is "currentpage"

Comment: Since you are already using JavaScript, you can make a dummy element at the top of the menu and just update that with the selected content while hiding the original link with a class.

Comment: Yea, the only way you can do that is with jquery or javascript. if you are using jquery, use the jquery.on('click', function(){// add codes here }); to do it,

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Flexbox` and change `order` with js.

```js
$('nav a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass('currentpage').siblings().removeClass('currentpage');
})
```

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.currentpage {
  order: -1;
  font-size: 30px;
}
a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="currentpage">Link 3</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: This doesn't move the currentpage to the top of the list like what the op is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have created an example in the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oc5sqd6m/2/), I have tested it, it works

```
$('.nav a').on('click',function(){
  $(this).parent().children('a').removeClass();
  $(this).addClass('currentpage');
  console.log($(this))
  console.log($(this).parent().children('a').eq(0))
  $(this).insertBefore($(this).parent().children('a').eq(0));
})
```

In this example i use jquery 1.9

The steps are:

1. I remove all the existing currentpage in a, incase there is some that are not removed properly.
2. I add the currentpage class into the one you have just click.
3. I move the one you click to the first one under nav